# TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of null! MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angular, post, mean-stack, connection-refused

I am making a simple ToDoApp with MEAN (Angular 2) stack but I have a problem with the http.post request. Always when I am running the post method, the current JSON object gets inserted into the database. But right after I get an error message and also my current server connection breaks down.

Insert method:

[image: post method]

The error in the console:

[image: Console error]

CORS is allowed on the backend side and I don't know what else to try.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are few mistakes in your question.. use the right one

Comment: You may not stringify your body (task object). I would try to remove RequestOptions instance and set the post method like this: 
this.http.post('api/task', task, {headers})...
Hope help you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because `http.post` returns a `promise`, not an `array` as you assume by calling `.map` on the result.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post.

A valid example would be:

```
$http
.post('/someUrl', data, config)
.then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: That's maybe a solution for AngularJS but i am using Angular2 and i think i can't use your answer!